# Cancelling Async webservice call

Tags: c#, web-services

In my application certain asmx webservice calls are made asynchronously. Is there some way I can cancel the async call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for **Aborting Requests** in this document: [Asynchronous Web Service Calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480512.aspx)